# when remote-debugging with lldb, does the remote binary need debug symbols?

Tags: remote-debugging, lldb, gdbserver

With gdb, the remote binary can be stripped, and local binary contain debug symbols.
With lldb, I can use `gdb-remote` to connect to the remote gdbserver, but how do I tell lldb where to find debug symbols? `lldb local-binary` doesn't seem to recognize debug infos in local-binary.
My steps:

- on ubuntu16.04(the remote), run `gdbserver --attach :9988 6379`, output is

```
Attached; pid = 6379
Listening on port 9988
```

- on macos catalina(the host), run `lldb target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/server`, in prompt run `gdb-remote`, output is

```
❯ lldb target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/server
(lldb) target create "target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/server"
Current executable set to '/Users/sify/Source/test/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/server' (x86_64).
(lldb) gdb-remote remote-ubuntu-ip:9988
Process 6379 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGTRAP
    frame #0: 0x000000000208b705 server`epoll_pwait + 24
server`epoll_pwait:
->  0x208b705 <+24>: movl   %eax, %ecx
    0x208b707 <+26>: cmpl   $-0x26, %eax
    0x208b70a <+29>: jne    0x208b71a                 ; <+45>
    0x208b70c <+31>: testq  %r8, %r8
Target 0: (server) stopped.
(lldb) source info
error: No debug info for the selected frame.
(lldb) source list
(lldb) c
Process 6379 resuming
(lldb) process detach
Process 6379 detached
```

You can see lldb shows assembly code, no debug info, though I can continue or detach. The executable does have debug info:

```
❯ file target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/server
target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/server: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Comment: Can you show how you are doing this?  If you first create the target (either by specifying the file on the command line or using `target create` and then connecting to the remote with `gdb-remote` lldb should use the target you've specified.  If it has debug info in it or has pointers to separate debug info that can be resolved locally, lldb should use that.

Comment: Before you run the `gdb-remote` command, can you run the command `source list -n epoll_pwait -s server`?  Does that show source information?  If it doesn't then for some reason this function ended up without debug info.  If it does, then run `image list server` before and after the `gdb-remote` command.  The second column in that listing is the UUID for the binary.  Were they the same before and after the attach?

Answer (score 0):

Mapping did the trick for me:

```
settings append target.source-map /remote-src /local-src
```

... and for some reason `settings set` did not.